# Native Object Class from WinControl?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to take a WinTable object and cast it to its native object type as such:

```
CustomControl control = (CustomControl) this.UIMap.UIMainWindow.UICustomControl.NativeElement;
```

Then I want to treat the resulting `CustomControl` as I would in the source code for my program like `control.DoAThing()`, I have already referenced the .dll containing the `CustomControl` class but the problem is that `.NativeElement;` is returning a type `Object[]` rather than an `Object` like the [definition of the function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.NativeElement%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) says it should.

Is `.NativeElement` the way to go or am I misunderstanding its purpose?

**UPDATE:** I checked the types of the objects in the resulting `Object[]` and the first one is of type `System.__ComObject` and the 2nd is `System.Int32` but I'm not sure what either of these represent...

Comment: It looks like you're not getting the managed object, but just the DLL the com control resides in and an integer (intended as a pointer) for the entry point of the object.
(which is incidentally also why doing this requires full trust for the immediate caller)
My guess is `.NativeElement` isn't supposed to do what you expect it to.
What is `CustomControl` ? Did you write that class yourself?

Comment: @TimothyGroote No, it is a third-party control. I do have access to the source code however.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that since Array inherits Object, that Array<Object> aka Object[] is an Object and doesn't really violate the return type

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you posted your code for your `CustomControl` and `UICustomControl` classes. Based on my vague understanding of your problem, the following might work: try it out and post the results.

```
object[] native = 
  this.UIMap.UIMainWindow.UICustomControl.NativeElement as object[];
if ((native[0] != null) && (native[0] is IAccessible)) {
    IAccessible a = native[0] as IAccessible;
    if (a is CustomControl)
        CustomControl control = (CustomControl)a;
}
```

Comment: What guarantee do you have that the first item in the array is even defined, let alone the object you're looking for?

Comment: I have already tried this before, the result was an error message saying that an object reference was not set aka `IAccessible a = native[0] as IAccessible;` didn't work. I don't think posting the custom control source code is relevant in this case, theoretically my issue could be applied to any control including default Windows Forms controls.

Answer (score 0):

NativeElement gets the object used by the underlying Automation Technology.

If you're using WinForms, NativeElement will return an object[] where the fist index is the IAccessible. I believe any other values will be childids for MSAA use but I've never used them personally.

```
public static IAccessible AsIAccessible(this WinControl control)
{
    var native = control.NativeElement as object[];
    return native[0] as IAccessible;
}
```

If you're using WPF, NativeElement will return an AutomationElement.

```
public static AutomationElement AsAutomationElement(this WpfControl control)
{
    return control.NativeElement as AutomationElement
}
```

if you're using Web, NativeElement will return the appropriate mshtml interface

```
public static T AsNativeHtml<T>(this HtmlControl control) where T : HTMLElement
{
    return control.NativeElement as T
}

myDiv.AsNativeHtml<HTMLDivElement>()
```

However, I do not believe there is a way to get the Native object class without hooking into the target process in some way.

I've tried to make custom wrappers of [hawkeye](https://github.com/odalet/Hawkeye2) in the past. Which is a ui inspection tool that can get and set native .Net properties. However, I've had limited success due to complexity and time constraints.